# What is the proper reserved product ID to test in-app subscriptions with Android?

Tags: android, testing, google-play, subscriptions

Per [Google's documentation on 'Testing In-app Billing'](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_testing.html), there are four reserved product IDs to be used for in-app testing of the billing and subscription services:

- android.test.purchased
- android.test.canceled
- android.test.refunded
- android.test.item_unavailable

What is the reserved product ID that we can use to test in-app subscriptions end-to-end, which was introduced by google last week? android.test.purchased applies to the "inapp" product type only, not the "subs" product type.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to test in-app subscriptions by creating an inexpensive test subscription that is only shown on debug builds (but is in all other ways a valid product on Google Play). [By using a test account described here](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_testing.html) I am able to purchase the subscription product and test end-to-end.

Here is what it says about test accounts:

> To test your in-app billing implementation with actual in-app
>   purchases, you will need to register at least one test account on the
>   Google Play publisher site. You cannot use your developer account to
>   test the complete in-app purchase process because Google Wallet does
>   not let you buy items from yourself. If you have not set up test
>   accounts before, see Setting up test accounts.
>
> Also, a test account can purchase an item in your product list only if
>   the item is published. The application does not need to be published,
>   but the item does need to be published.
>
> When you use a test account to purchase items, the test account is
>   billed through Google Wallet and your Google Wallet Merchant account
>   receives a payout for the purchase. Therefore, you may want to refund
>   purchases that are made with test accounts, otherwise the purchases
>   will show up as actual payouts to your merchant account.

Comment: you may be redirect the future visiters to given link below instead of your link: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-test
Future visiter can directly see your commented lines into developer document.

Comment: check this link: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#testing-purchases
Requirements for using test purchases

If you plan to use test purchases, please note the requirements and limitations below:
1) Test purchases is only supported for license test accounts when the app is using the In-app Billing v3 API.
2) Test purchases are only supported for in-app products, not for in-app subscriptions.
How can you successfully test subscription? I mean have you paid product payment from the google wallet and then get refund? or how can I test without giving any payment?